# onItemSelected() called before setOnItemSelectedListener()

Tags: android

I am calling `setSelection` on a Spinner before calling `setOnItemSelectedListener`, why is the `onItemSelected` method firing?

```
public class MyActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MySpinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        // spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(null); // tried this also
        spinner.setSelection(1);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onItemSelected() firing");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably `setOnItemSelectedListener` is just passing reference to your `OnItemSelectedListener` (immediately) while `setSelection` is connected with "look" of `View` (there is a state `state_selected`) so it will be called when layout finish drawing - your selection will be "posted". `setSelection` works smth like `spinner.post(spinner.setSelectionImmediatelly(position))`

1. setting selection, `View` is busy with own drawing, so selection will show after `View` finish own methods
2. set reference to `Listener`
3. after a while (very short) `View` will draw itself (after `onCreate`) and check that it should redraw own drawables - new selection is pending so it will be drawn then with checking is there any `Listener`. and yes, it is, set inside `onCreate`

if you want to "fix" this maybe set yout `Listener` in `onResume` method or use [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) of your spinner

Comment: I ended up creating a class level integer and checked the number of times `setSelection` was called before performing the actual desired action (a solution found in many other Stack Overflow questions). But I believe you are correct, the call to `setSelection` is asynchronous and fires when the view shows or at least after the `onCreate` method has completed. I did not try setting the listener in `onResume`, but suspect that may also work.